# filter gitlab commit history using commit sha

Tags: git, gitlab

Is there any way by which the GitLab commits history can be filtered based on the commit SHA? I tried looking up on their community blog and was able to know that such a feature had been requested in the past. I am currently using GitLab Community Edition 10.6.2.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Filtered in what way?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, Currently gitlab offers to filter the commits by the commit message. So what I require is to filter the commits using the commit SHA that we obtain. This type of filtering would help in finding the exact commit whenever required.

Comment: Have you considered writing a script that calls commits from API and then filters it using SHA's

Comment: If you have cloned the repo, you could do this locally

Comment: @ArihantGodha@evolutionxbox, both these methods seem to be helpful to resolve my issue. The commit API by gitlab for retrieving single commit as well as trying to get it locally from cloned repo. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the commit by SHA using Gitlab API : [GET /projects/:id/repository/commits/:sha](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#get-a-single-commit)

```bash
curl -s "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/repository/commits/<SHA>?private_token=<TOKEN>"
```